# what can to_string() return in NaN cases

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Im using VS 2012 and I encountered really irritating behaviour(sometimes my float is NaN):

```
auto dbgHelp = std::to_string(myFloat);
```

`dbgHelp` ends up containing **5008** charachters ( you cant invent this stuff up)
most of them 0, 
it ends up with :
0.#INF00

So is this a bug or standard allows idiotic return values like this ?

fix is trivial, for me to manualy do the proper thig with ternary operator and `isnan()`
but I wonder if standard is specific regarding this...

Comment: `float` does not have a value for `NaN`.  What is the actual value of your `myFloat`?

Comment: You could always trace into `to_string` to get a better idea of why it might be failing like it is.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN

Comment: MSVC sources are littered with macros redirections, TMP and dbg checks...  :D

Comment: and like i said this is about if standard allows this idiocy or it is defined precisely.

Comment: That's not NaN, it is Infinity.  You are probably dividing by zero.  The standard doesn't describe how many zeros infinite has, the std::num_put() function in `<xlocnum>` thinks 5000 is more than enough.  The bug has already [been filed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/810452/bad-to-string-result-for-infinity).  It appears to have something to do with an early draft for std::to_string(), characterized as "obnoxious" before by STL.  Strong words.

Comment: I like STL, but blaming iso for returning 5k string... = LOL + cry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::to_string` overloads are specified in [string.conversions]/7:

> ```
> string to_string(int val);
> string to_string(unsigned val);
> string to_string(long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long val);
> string to_string(long long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long long val);
> string to_string(float val);
> string to_string(double val);
> string to_string(long double val);
> ```
>
> <sup>7</sup> *Returns:* Each function returns a `string` object holding the character representation of the value of its argument that would be generated by calling `sprintf(buf, fmt, val)` with a format specifier of `"%d"`, `"%u"`, `"%ld"`, `"%lu"`, `"%lld"`, `"%llu"`, `"%f"`, `"%f"`, or `"%Lf"`, respectively, where `buf` designates an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

`sprintf` is detailed in C99 (N1256 actually) 7.19.6.6/2:

> The `sprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into
>   an array (specified by the argument `s`) rather than to a stream. A null character is written
>   at the end of the characters written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If
>   copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Jumping over to 7.19.6.1 for `fprintf`, the format flags are described in paragraph 8. Specifically, for the `f` format:

> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to
>   decimal notation in the style *[−]ddd.ddd*, where the number of digits after
>   the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the
>   precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the # flag is
>   not specified, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal-point
>   character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to
>   the appropriate number of digits.
>
> A `double` argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles
>   `[-]inf` or `[-]infinity` — which style is implementation-defined. A
>   double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles
>   `[-]nan` or `[-]nan(`*n-char-sequence*`)` — which style, and the meaning of
>   any *n-char-sequence*, is implementation-defined. The `F` conversion specifier
>   produces `INF`, `INFINITY`, or `NAN` instead of `inf`, `infinity`, or `nan`,
>   respectively.

Putting it all together, when `float foo` is positive infinity, `std::to_string(foo)` should return `std::string("inf")`.